# Where should I go for questions about the Finnish language?

Tags: finnish

I was looking for a site here for Finnish language, because I could *nowhere* find any hint on how double letters are spoken. Is "tt" spoken as "t" holding not as short as it would be, or is it "t", very, very, little pause, and "t" again?

Sorry if this is the wrong site to ask, but this is part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SE does not have a Finnish site.
2. The languages codidact site can be used also for these types of questions. https://languages.codidact.com/
3. Hard consonants (k, t, p are common ones; not m, n, l), when doubled mean a glottal stop before the consonant itself. I recommend using Forvo or Youtube videos to hear people pronounce these words to get a sense of the pronunciation.

Example of double k (hard consonant): https://forvo.com/word/tukka/

Example of double m (soft consonant): https://forvo.com/word/tommi/

I am not a linguist; pardon non-technical terminology.